# Nativeint Bigarray seems to be unsigned

Tags: c, arrays, int, ocaml, ffi

I want to return int-arrays from a C-library to a OCaml program. In order to do so, I thought I'd just wrap them in a `Bigarray.Array1.t`. Below is a small demo of the C-stubs:

```
/* nativeintarray.c */ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <caml/memory.h>
#include <caml/bigarray.h>

CAMLprim value make_array(value unit) {
  CAMLparam1(unit);
  int* a = calloc (1, sizeof(int));
  a[0] = -1;
  /* Create a C-style bigarray, yes it is a memory leak */
  CAMLreturn(caml_ba_alloc_dims(CAML_BA_NATIVE_INT | CAML_BA_C_LAYOUT, 1, a, 1));
}
```

My example program looks like this:

```
(* nativeintarray.ml *)
open Bigarray

(** Type for int arrays from/to C *)
type ivector = (nativeint, nativeint_elt, c_layout) Array1.t

external make_array : unit -> ivector = "make_array"

let () =
  Printf.printf "%nd\n" (make_array ()).{0}
```

Since nativeint is a signed integer, I expect the program to output -1, instead it gives:

```
% ocamlbuild nativeintarray_c.o                                        
Finished, 1 target (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
% ocamlbuild -package bigarray -lflags nativeintarray_c.o nativeintarray.native
Finished, 4 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
% ./nativeintarray.native 
4294967295
```

As I said, I naively expected `nativeint` to match the `int` in my local C-compiler, but this is obviously not the case. Can somebody explain this?

Platform: 
Ocaml 4.02.3, gcc 6.1.1, all 64 bit

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked `sizeof(int)` is really `8` in your environment?

In Win64, OCaml 4.03.0 with x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (MinGW64 compiler of Cygwin), your code runs just you have described (prints `4294967295`, instead of `-1`).  There, `sizeof(int)` does *not* return `8` but `4`.

Changing `int` by `long long` fixed the issue.  I am not a C guru, so I may be wrong but OCaml's `nativeint` may not be `int` of the underlying C compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In C `sizeof(int)` may not be `8` on a 64-bit platform.

If you wish to use the `nativeint` type in your C bindings the simplest is to include `<caml/config.h>` and use the `intnat` type defined there.

So to rewrite your example:

```
/* nativeintarray.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <caml/config.h>
#include <caml/memory.h>
#include <caml/bigarray.h>

CAMLprim value make_array(value unit) {
  CAMLparam1(unit);
  intnat* a = calloc (1, sizeof(intnat));
  a[0] = -1;
  /* Create a C-style bigarray, yes it is a memory leak */
  CAMLreturn(caml_ba_alloc_dims(CAML_BA_NATIVE_INT | CAML_BA_C_LAYOUT, 1, a, 1));
}
```